# How to stop loop animation immediately in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve loop animation in react native. I am able to stop the animation as well, but it stops only after finishing the running animation in progress. Is there a way to stop it immediately. Since I am changing `state` value , I don't think I can use `Animated.loop`.

Edit: I tried stopping animation using

```
Animated.timing(this.state.opacity).stop()
```

But this had no effect on animation, it just kept going. So I added a boolean to control it, which works, but only after finishing the ongoing loop of animation.

Here is my code

```
this.state = {
   varyingText: 'location',
   stopAnimation: false,
   opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
};


componentDidMount = () => {
    this.startAnimation();
  };

  startAnimation = () => {
    if (this.state.stopAnimation) return;

    Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000
    }).start(() => {
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000
      }).start(() => {
        this.setState({
          varyingText: 'location 1',
        }, () => {
          Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 1000
          }).start(() => {
            Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
              toValue: 0,
              duration: 1000
            }).start(() => {
              this.setState({
                varyingText: 'location 2',
              }, () => {
                Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
                  toValue: 1,
                  duration: 1000
                }).start(() => {
                  Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 1000
                  }).start(() => {
                    this.setState({
                      varyingText: 'location 3',
                    }, () => this.startAnimation())
                  })
                })
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
    });
  };

stopAnimation = () => {
    this.setState({
      stopAnimation: true,
    });
  };

render() {
    const opacityStyle = {
      opacity: this.state.opacity,
    };
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
          <Animated.Text style={...opacityStyle}>
             {this.state.varyingText}
          </Animated.Text>

          <Button
             onPress={this.stopAnimation}
             title="Stop"
             color="#841584"
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

In the code, if I stop the animation when text is `location 1`, it stops but only after showing `location 2`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022964/how-to-stop-react-native-animation for stopping animations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop react-native animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022964/how-to-stop-react-native-animation)

Comment: I am able to stop animation, it's just that it runs for few more times before it finally comes to stop.

Comment: The linked post explains how to stop all animations immediately - you aren't calling `Animated.timing(..).stop()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I tried that, that was the first attempt. But the way I am using loop animation, that approach didn't stop animation at all.